# Flutter keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

I am filling a email textFormField and using the keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress. I want the keyboard to use only lowercase letters inside the TextFormField. How to do this in flutter?

This is the TextFormField i am using.

```
TextFormField(
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    return value.isEmpty
                                        ? 'Please enter your email address.'
                                        : RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                                                .hasMatch(value)
                                            ? null
                                            : 'Please enter a valid email.';
                                  },
                                  controller: _emailController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    email = value.toLowerCase();
                                  },
                                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                                    hintText: 'Enter your email',
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.email,
                                      color: Color(0x759E9E9E),
                                    ),
                                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.clear,
                                      ),
                                      splashRadius: 25.0,
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _emailController.clear();
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `TextFormField` `validator` like this :

```
return Form(
autovalidate: true,
child: Container(
TextFormField(
validator: (String val) {

if (val.isEmpty)
return 'We need something to search for';
else
{
  // Use your TextEditingController to get text
_textController.text=val.toLowerCase();
setState((){});
return null;
},
},
),
),
);
```

**Edit** : You have edited your question :
Modify your validator like this :

```
validator: (value) {
                                    if(value.isEmpty) return 'Please enter your email address.';
else{

                   _emailController.text=value.toLowerCase();
                    setState((){});
                           return RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                                                .hasMatch(value)
                                            ? null
                                            : 'Please enter a valid email.';

}
                             

     },
```

Comment: Is there any possibilities to disable the captialization of the keyboard.

Comment: At this point I don't know, I will search for it in the docs and edit the answer if find something useful

Comment: This helps me when validating the form, it automatically changes the UPPERCASE to lowercase.

Comment: Are you talking about second edit ? I find it interesting that I can't find constant 'email' in TextInputType class . I think this class has been modified and email is changed to emailAddress . You can see it here : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputType-class.html   This also means my second edit is wrong ?